# using R shiny server together with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Am using ggplot to plot a pie chart as in the code below in RStudio and its working fine. the problem is when i want to use R shiny server.

```
indicatorTotals<-tapply(anc_data$Total,anc_data$Indicator,sum)
graphdatapie <- as.data.frame(indicatorTotals)
c <- ggplot(graphdatapie, aes(x=rownames(graphdatapie),y=indicatorTotals,fill = 
    indicatorTotals)) + geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity")
print(c + coord_polar(theta = "y"))
```

the data is this format

```
                       indicatorTotals
ANC 1st visit                   248777
ANC 2nd visit                   231914
ANC 3rd visit                   162062
ANC 4th or more visits           99528
```

I get the following error message from the R shiny server ui.R.

```
Error:object 'graphdatapie' not found.
```

What could be the problem???

Comment: It would be good to include all the shiny code and some sample data so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PeterFine, Thanks, i managed the problem by adding environment=environment()  to the ggplot function

Comment: @jonestats could you add your findings as an answer, in this way this question will have value to the community.

Comment: It'd be better to add the rownames as an explicit variable

Comment: yes please add data, and answer.. this would be very very helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the ggplot function: ***environment=environment()*** i.e

```
ggplot(graphdatapie, aes(x=rownames(graphdatapie),y=indicatorTotals,fill = 
             indicatorTotals), environment=environment())
```

Then restart the shiny-server. That will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. However, @hadley already suggested a better approach than to add `environment=environment()`. Could you add his solution to your answer?